# Апач игнорирует .htaccess.txt

Tags: .htaccess, apache, apache-modules

Вобщем второй день я что-то втупляю и не могу заставить апач обратить свой взор на .htaccess.txt лежащий в корне.
Что предпринимал:

- Создал сам файл .htaccess.txt Его содержимое:
  `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
  RewriteEngine on
  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
  RewriteRule ^/pub/([0-9]+) /pub/?id=$1`
- Убедился, что в httpd.conf раскомментирована строка 156 (`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`)
- Убедился, что в строках 229, 265, 378 стоит `AllowOverride All`

При этом сайт работает как обычно, никаких ошибок не выдаёт и никуда не перенаправляет соответственно.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вы .txt не пробовали убрать? переименуйте файл на .htaccess (без .txt)

Comment: @Maqsood .txt не входит в название, это расширение.

Comment: .htaccess серверами определяется как расширение, а .txt как просто текстовой файл, и не обрабатывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том что формат `.txt`, а его не должно быть!  Должно быть только `.htaccess`, но просто `.htaccess` блокнотом и другим стандартным редактором нельзя создать, но можно создать с примеру с помощью редактора [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/)

Comment: Едрёна вошь, действительно. Заработало!